# Quando e por que criar um aplicativo para dispositivo móvel?

Tags: aplicação-web, mobile, layout-responsivo, ux

Com a popularidade de dispositivos móveis tais como *smartphones* e *tablets*, capazes de executar aplicações bastante complexas, é cada vez mais comum que empresas desenvolvam aplicativos (*apps*) próprios. Os exemplos são inúmeros: há desde aplicativos de [cinemas e teatros](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/ingresso.com/id395159864?mt=8), a [agências de conteúdo/notícias](http://www.bbc.com/news/10628994) e até mesmo [igrejas](https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/universal/id661286949?mt=8).

Entretanto, o desenvolvimento de software para plataformas móveis têm seus próprios desafios, envolvendo não apenas portabilidade como principalmente diferentes formas de interação. Há também custo adicional, uma vez que é necessário construir um sistema adicional ao sistema Web existente (mesmo que responsivo).

Nesse sentido, eu gostaria de saber **quais são os fatores (técnicos, financeiros, de UX, etc) que justificam a criação de um aplicativo para um negócio/empresa?** Em outras palavras, por que vale a pena investir em um sistema computacional que vai ser instalado no equipamento móvel dos clientes, em detrimento de (ou como opção a) um único sistema web responsivo?

Comment: O maior desafio que eu vejo é o usuário querer instalar um app no seu aparelho. Qdo é algo q ele vai usar frequentemente, q lhe será muito útil, tudo bem. Eu vi em algum lugar que quase todos apps são usados apenas uma vez. Pra mim, salvo raras exceções, é mais um corrida ao ouro das tantas que já vimos. Mas eu não não entendo nada do assunto :P

Comment: É verdade. Mas há exceções. Esse aplicativo da BBC, por exemplo, tem funções muitíssimo interessantes que vão além do que se pode obter no acesso ao Website. Eu tenho as minhas visões a respeito (envolvendo vantagens funcionais do ponto de vista do usuário), mas fiz a pergunta pra tentar obter uma visão geral da comunidade ou de alguém que tenha experiência prática no assunto (que já construiu e publicou uma app assim na sua empresa, por exemplo).

Comment: Pois é. Eu tenho trabalhado praticamente só com sites responsivos, e não apps. Fiz um app pra uma empresa que precisava atualizar muito os produtos carregados, e aí as notificações push do app eram mais em conta (até por poder ser acessado offline), além de que era uma coisa meio 'interna'. Acho que depende muito da abordagem da empresa. Até porque com um app, vc está literalmente DENTRO do celular do seu público-alvo hehe. Aliás, esse app da BBC que vc comentou eu não conheço, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Sobre 'valer a pena', acredito que não seja tão simples, mas em questões financeiras, geralmente é muito mais em conta trabalhar somente com um site responsivo, até porque a programação mobile (e a própria publicação, no caso da Apple Store) tem um custo mais alto.

Comment: @DimasPante Por que você não oferece uma resposta focada nesse aspecto das notificações *push* e do *cache* (que parece ser algo que você observa como ponto de interesse)? Eu realmente não espero receber uma única resposta abrangente, mas algumas que se complementem. De fato, eu acredito que esse é o jeito ideal de gerar conhecimento bacana para a comunidade em assuntos complexos como esse. :)

Comment: Verdade, o problema é que pra focar em uma resposta, seria preciso saber o propósito hehe. Um e-commerce gigante, acessado mundialmente, ao meu ver, seria legal ter um App pela possibilidade de avisar o usuário de novos produtos via push, gravar as preferências dele, saber a localização, etc (Como a Amazon, tanto que o site deles não é responsivo). Ou um jornal local, que disponibilize as edições virtuais: um app é interessante pela questão do cache, mas não pelo valor do desenvolvimento. Nos dois exemplos, eu pessoalmente manteria o site, mesmo que não responsivo. O que você pensa sobre isso?

Comment: A pergunta está sendo discutida no Meta em: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4085/discuss%C3%A3o-sobre-a-pergunta-quando-e-por-que-criar-um-aplicativo-para-dispositiv

Comment: basta apenas pensar que o app não substitui o website mobile.. Entendeu? Se for criar um app para ser um substituto do site mobile, é como dar um tiro no pé .

Answer (score 7):

Entendendo melhor a pergunta (que é mais na linha de *"Por que fazer um app quando um site responsivo em princípio já dá conta do recado?"* e não de *"Quais funcionalidades nativas podem instigar uma empresa a querer criar um app para celular?"*), acredito que a resposta para a maioria dos casos é: não há por quê, a não ser que dar ao usuário um ícone para abrir o aplicativo em vez de guardar um *bookmark* seja importante para sua empresa. Ou então pelo menos faça um app híbrido que tem menos custo que um nativo.

Para uma minoria de casos o cache de dados offline pode ser importante.

Isso tende a ser cada vez mais verdade conforme as tecnologias web se aproximam de serem cidadãos de primeira-classe na plataforma nativa (em versões de Android a partir da 3.1 por exemplo já dá para se capturar fotos e vídeos usando somente tecnologias web. A partir da 5.0 a *WebView* é atualizável pela *app store*). Pelo menos assim diz o [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/nativedebate/). Mas no presente momento isso ainda não é verdade.

Para referência e para quem, como eu, entendeu que se tratava da segunda pergunta, segue a resposta dada inicialmente abaixo:

> Acredito que a resposta pode ser encontrada em artigos comparando
>   aplicativos nativos vs. híbridos vs. *web apps*.
>
> Atrativos de um app móvel nativo:
>
> - Acesso irrestrito ao hardware do dispositivo, como câmera, sensores, GPS;
> - Acesso a recursos do sistema operacional. No caso do Android por exemplo: notificações, gestos complexos (como por exemplo
>     redimensionar mapas com o *pinch zoom*), *widgets*, *services*,
>     *intents*;
> - Máxima performance geral comparada à que poderia ser obtida em uma *WebView*. Listas com grande número de itens, por exemplo, tornam-se lentas se a *WebView* não oferece aceleração por hardware, como é o
>     caso de plataformas mais antigas, ou esta não é usada. Mapas
>     não-nativos também têm problemas de performance;
> - Pode também usufruir das vantagens do ecossistema em que se encontra (um canal de marketing, distribuição e atualização, que é a *app
>     store*, e a monetização associada);
> - E finalmente o *look & feel* 100% nativo também é um fator que pode ser determinante na decisão de se criar um app nativo.
>
> Uma *web app* abre mão de tudo isso. Não chega nem a ter um ícone
>   *launcher* no celular para ser lembrada durante o uso do aparelho, é preciso guardar um *bookmark*. Em contrapartida, tem algumas
>   vantagens, como o custo reduzido de desenvolvimento que você já citou
>   e SEO.
>
> Uma solução intermediária para se ter acesso a essas funcionalidades
>   são os apps híbridos. Eles podem ser uma "casca" para um site
>   responsivo, ter um ícone *launcher* e, se não exigirem muita
>   performance ou uso de recursos e *look & feel* nativo dão conta do
>   recado e exigirem um custo de desenvolvimento intermediário entre o
>   nativo e o site.

Comment: Mas, por que o acesso irrestrito aos recursos do sistema operacional são interessantes para *a empresa*? Pense assim, como esse argumento pode ser usado pra justificar o gasto para o seu chefe (que não entende muito desses aspectos)? Sobre o desempenho (*performance*), na aplicação Web o recurso computacional não é do servidor? Não sei se cabe a comparação. As vantagens do ecossistema é um ponto interessante, mas que vale pras empresas cujo ponto focal do serviço é a app (eles vendem a app). Vale também para outros negócios (como o caso da BBC)? ...

Comment: ... Afinal, se não há app instalada, não há preocupação com distribuição ou atualização. Ainda cabe a comparação? Finalmente, look and feel é algo interessante, mas talvez seja o fator menos relevante para a decisão, não? Fiz essas perguntas pra você tentar complementar a resposta (isto é, por favor, não precisa responder por aqui nos comentários). :)

Comment: Rapaz, tomei um -1 e a pessoa não explicou por quê... Mas enfim. Talvez eu não tenha entendido a pergunta, ou ela poderia ter sido formulada de maneira diferente. Posso até elaborar a resposta, mas acredito que os recursos que citei falam por si próprios, então se existe a necessidade deles, a escolha é desenvolver o app nativamente ou como híbrido. Agora, se você parte do princípio de que um web app ou site responsivo atende a situação, então a necessidade desses recursos não existe e não há por que implementá-los.

Comment: Não fui eu quem votou contra a sua resposta. Eu só argumentei com alguns aspectos que eu achei que podiam ser mais bem explorados pra tornar a sua resposta melhor. Infelizmente essas coisas acontecem (votos negativos). Eu diria pra você não se preocupar tanto. Toda comunidade é assim mesmo, existem pessoas com opiniões diferentes.

Comment: Eu imaginei que não teria sido você. :) Por favor não interprete meu comentário anterior como defensivo. Apenas comentei sobre o voto porque o site estimula o votante a justificar o voto nesse caso ou a sugerir uma melhoria à resposta.

Comment: Dei um trato na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esforço. :) O seu segundo entendimento está mais correto para o que eu havia imaginado, mas a resposta ainda não me agrada porque você basicamente diz que "não há por que" e eu não concordo totalmente. Algumas vezes há um bom porquê, quando de fato a versão mobile oferece *algum valor* para o usuário (nem que seja segurança, no caso do token físico para acesso bancário do exemplo do Itaú do colega @GuilhermeNascimento). O que eu realmente intencionava com a pergunta era elencar esse tipo de argumento, mas vejo que a pergunta é realmente muito ampla.

Answer (score 7):

### Aplicativo vs Site responsivo

A única vantagem de realmente desenvolver um aplicativo além ou no lugar de um site mobile (ou responsivo) seria o fato dos navegadores móveis terem mais limitações. As três características dos aplicativos que podem tornar o desenvolvimento vantajoso são (eu acredito ser apenas estas duas):

1. Adicionar características customizadas que a maioria dos navegadores móveis hoje não suportam, alguns exemplos:

   - Tirar uma foto e mandar diretamente pro aplicativo, sem a necessidade de selecionar na galeria.
   - Gravar áudio e subir diretamente para o aplicativo
2. Coletar dados do cliente com maior facilidade e com menor risco de perda para direcionar "propaganda" ou "produtos" destinados ao perfil do cliente (sim as empresas fazem isto)
3. "Manter logado" (evitar que tenha que digitar a senha toda vez que abrir o navegador) ou permitir múltiplos contas logadas, esta característica apesar de um pouco incomum pode ser eventualmente necessária.

### Consideração sobre as vantagens de se desenvolver

O que no meu ponto de vista faz o desenvolvimento/investimento em aplicativos Móveis valer a pena são:

1. O numero de usuário móveis (que podem vir a se tornar clientes) já é maior que o numero de usuários "domésticos"
2. O tempo de acesso dos usuários móveis já é superior ao dos usuários domésticos.
3. Publicidade, aonde temos maior números de usuários e com maior tempo de acesso é um ótimo local para apresentar a marca ou produto.
4. Produtividade, se o usuário sendo ele cliente ou funcionário necessita executar uma tarefa aonde não tem um equipamento como *notebook/desktop* e internet, o seu smartphone pode ser uma "mão na roda" para executar tarefas a "qualquer momento".

### Internet Residencial x Internet Móvel

Conforme dados de 2013 á começo de 2014 conforme os gráficos do *nic.br* mostra que aproximadamente existem 27,2 milhões de residencias no Brasil com acesso a internet.

[image: domicilio]

Os gráficos do mesmo período mostram que 52,2 milhões de usuários tem acesso a internet em seus dispositivos mobile

[image: 2g/3g tablets, smartphones]

### Tempo gasto com smartphones já é maior do que com computadores

Apesar do link que citei no titulo não se tratar do Brasil, eu acredito que isto também é válido para a maioria dos países com "inclusão digital".

Realizado com pessoas dos Estados Unidos, do Reino Unido e da Itália, a pesquisa mostra que os consumidores de tecnologia está gastando muito mais tempo em seus smartphones do que em computadores — sendo que redes sociais lideram esse nicho com bastante folga. É preciso dizer ainda que a televisão ainda é a líder absoluta em horas de utilização e tecnologia, chegando a ser cinco vezes mais utilizada.

Nos Estados Unidos, enquanto os smartphones são utilizados por mais 34 horas ao mês, os computadores ficam perto das 27 horas — contra 185 horas que os consumidores passam em frente à televisão. Na Inglaterra esses números são, respectivamente, 41 horas, 29 horas e 129 horas. Já na Itália o tempo gasto com as comunicações fica em 37 horas, 18 horas e 143 horas.

[image: Comparação TV vs Móvel vs Residencial]

Fontes:

- http://www.nielsen.com/us/en/insights/news/2014/how-smartphones-are-changing-consumers-daily-routines-around-the-globe.html
- http://www.tecmundo.com.br/celular/51768-tempo-gasto-com-smartphones-ja-e-maior-do-que-com-computadores.htm

### Opinião pessoal quanto ao desenvolvimento

Eu não posso afirmar, mas é o que eu notei com alguns aplicativos populares, um exemplo é o do Itaú, que começou bem limitado e com o tempo foi recebendo novas funcionalidades e melhoras praticidade e facilidade do uso (interface).

- Considerando estes fatos, penso eu que se o aplicativo é voltado para os clientes devemos investir moderadamente (um aplicativo mais simples) e ter um canal de feedback para receber sugestões, em outras palavras não arriscar todas as fichas, no entanto se o aplicativo "vingar" e se tornar útil ou necessário, então aumentaríamos os investimentos.
- Se o aplicativo é voltado para o funcionário de uma determinada empresa, então o cenário é diferente, deve-se investir "tempo", "qualidade" e "testes" e ter um canal de feedback também.

Ambas situações ao meu ver devem ter no minimo um desenvolvedor com experiencia em interface mobile e um outro desenvolvedor que tenha conhecimento do sistema que está portanto para o sistema móvel.

Comment: Obrigado também pelo esforço da resposta. Eu ainda discordo que a pergunta seja opinativa. Ela é apenas mais subjetiva do que uma pergunta que só apresenta código. Mas realmente, há muita razão no fato dela ser ampla. As duas respostas que já existem só comprovam isso por terem focos tão distintos. Eu votei positivamente nas duas pelo esforço, mas realmente agora eu concordo que a pergunta deveria ser fechada.