# O Xamarin é uma opção viável para desenvolvimento mobile?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

Preciso desenvolver para mobile e estava pensando no Xamarin como opção, e só depois fui dar uma pesquisada e descobri que:

1. O Xamarin é pago, e o preço é meio salgado para uma reles licença individual.
2. Não há como desenvolver o app 100% em C#, a maioria diz que 75% do código vai ser escrito em C# e o restante na linguagem nativa do sistema.
3. Para compilar apps para iOS vou ter que comprar um Mac.

Com estes três pontos em mente gostaria de saber se o Xamarin é uma opção viável?

Comment: Eu acho que se você sabe o que vai fazer o Xamarin é bom

Comment: E tem como, no meu ponto de vista, desenvolver 95% em C#

Comment: `Xamarin` agora é gratuito no seu caso

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Se não estou errado, segue os mesmos termos de utilização do VisualStudio Community 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não vou responder a parte que pede opinião porque não é objetivo deste site e não deveria ser de nenhum, já que isto não resolve problema de ninguém.

É óbvio que é viável, afinal tem um monte de gente fazendo isto.

Cada um sabe onde seu calo dói e vai ver se a ferramenta atende em todos pontos. Não dá para pessoas aleatórias na internet dizer o que é bom para você.

Nunca ouvi falar que precisa usar outra linguagem para fazer outras partes. Até onde eu sei dá para fazer 100% em C#. Claro que pode existir alguma coisa muito específica e rara que não dê para fazer bem em C# porque o Xamarin ainda não está 100%. Não acho que isto torne ele muito menos interessante. Ainda há ganhos no seu uso.

O que pode acontecer é ter que fazer algumas partes em C# mesmo que só sejam úteis para uma das plataformas. Isto é comum, mas existem [técnicas para reduzir esta necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127567/101).

E lembre-se que quase todo aplicativo tem uma parte no servidor também que pode servir todas plataformas.

Claro que ele não faz milagre. Fazer na linguagem nativa pode dar um resultado ligeiramente melhor. Aí depende do que acha que é mais importante. Aprender e usar 3 tecnologias diferentes e fazer o melhor possível ou usar uma só e fazer o necessário que ainda é muito bom.

Dá para compilar para iOS em uma máquina virtual ou usar um serviço externo. A própria [Xamarin oferece um](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se programar em outra linguagem também precisará de algo assim.

A Microsoft disponibiliza o [produto principal gratuitamente](https://www.xamarin.com/platform?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Se o aplicativo é útil, serve para alguma coisa e pode comercializado, monetizado, etc., <strike>o custo da licença é irrelevante</strike>. O ganho por aproveitar o grosso do código pode ser tão vantajoso que <strike>o custo se torna irrisório</strike>.

O único problema é quando o [aplicativo foi fruto de voluntarismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73289/101), e tem muito disto das lojas. Aí fica no prejuízo mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sua resposta me foi muito útil, mesmo assim quero ir um pouco mais fundo. A empresa desse cara faz web marketing e o principal dele é na criação de lojas virtuais, e alguns clientes dele pedem/precisam de apps, principalmente em Android. Pelo que ele me disse, as aplicações em geral devem mostrar um catálogo dos produtos da loja, e permitir a compra diretamente pelo app ou através de redirecionamento pelo browser. Isso não me parece tão complicado, exceto pela parte da integração com o banco da lojas. Me pergunto então se pelo menos no Android é possível fazer isso 100% em C#. Sabe me dizer?

Comment: Isso você só vai descobrir tentando. Ninguém vai conseguir te responder. Nem você sabe ainda o que será preciso.

Comment: Ezequiel, tudo que é possível ser feito para Android com Java é possível ser feito em C#. O Xamarin encapsula todas as chamadas de todas as APIs do Android, inclusive das APIs de suporte, que é a base de como devem ser feitos apps com Design Material. Não existe nenhum cenário que o C# não cubra, e falo isso por experiência. Só faz sentido usar algo em Java quando você já tem um jar/war implementado ou alguma dependência de algum terceiro que não faz sentido reimplementar, ai você consegue criar um projeto de Binding e puxar/usar esta dependência.