# Xamarin.Forms Portable ou Xamarin.Forms Shared

Tags: .net, xamarin

Qual a diferença entre um projeto Xamarin.Forms Portable ou Xamarin.Forms Shared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Portable é aplicado em uma versão limitada (*subset*) do *framework* que pode rodar em todas plataformas. Qualquer código tem que ser escrito considerando estas limitações e se precisar fazer alguma especialização, isto deve ocorrer com injeção de dependência ou alguma técnica que dê o mesmo resultado (até mesmo decisões simples com `if`). É algo mais dinâmico.

[image: Portable Class Library]

O Shared usa um código desenvolvido para todas plataformas e as especializações são decididas por meio de compilação condicional `#ifdef`. Ou seja, o código fonte pode ser único, mas será gerada uma versão diferente para cada plataforma. É algo mais estático.

[image: Shared Project]

Isto já não faz tanto sentido mais, tem soluções melhores.

Comment: quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada abordagem?

Comment: Em resumo acho que já está implícito na resposta, o Portable é mais rápido de desenvolver, mas não fica tão bom. Detalhadamente não caberia aqui, teria que ser uma nova pergunta.