# Comparativo Xamarin.Forms Portable ou Shared

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.portable

O desenvolvimento mobile com Xamarin.Forms nos propicia duas abordagens:

**Portable:**

> Crie uma Biblioteca de Classes Portátil (PCL) que visa as plataformas
>   que você deseja oferecer suporte e usa Interfaces para fornecer
>   funcionalidade específica da plataforma.

**Shared:**

> Usa o tipo projeto recurso compartilhado para organizar seu
>   código-fonte e usa diretrizes '#if do compilador conforme necessário
>   para gerenciar requisitos específicos da plataforma.

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada abordagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso agora tem pouca relevância. Muita coisa mudou, foi criado o .NET Standard, outras formas de organizar as coisas no Xamarin, e em 2020 surge o .NET 5 que muda ainda mais.

Eu não trabalho com Xamarin (ainda) então não posso falar om experiência, e para não ter que confiar no que um zé mané como eu, eu fui pesquisar sobre o assunto.

Encontrei um [artigo do Miguel de Icaza](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2016/Jan-22.html), o criador do Xamarin. Ele recomenda o uso do Shared em contraposto do Jason Smith que prefere o PCL.

Achei interessante porque ele validou uma coisa que eu sempre pensei. Com `partial` nem sempre precisamos usar `#ifdef`.

Parece opinião, e até é. Na verdade se existem as duas formas, elas atendem situações diferentes e gostos diferentes. Eu fico com o Miguel, não porque ele é o bambambam da coisa, mas porque faz mais sentido pra mim. Vejamos

## PCL

- O mesmo código pode ser usado para diversas plataformas
- Toda manutenção afeta todas plataformas de forma única, não precisa replicar
- O executável pode ser compartilhado entre projetos diferentes
- Permite que a aplicação seja *plugável* dinamicamente

Mas

- Somente um *subset* do .NET está disponível
- A aplicação só pode usar as partes mais básicas que conseguem funcionar uniformemente em todas plataformas suportadas.
- Nem sempre terá a melhor experiência com o usuário
- O código tende a se tornar complexo para tentar fazer funcionar bem em todas plataformas

## Shared

- É fácil compartilhar o código com diversos projetos e algumas partes do código podem funcionar em todas plataformas
- Pode usar diretivas de compilação ou `partial` para compilar as partes de cada plataformas
- O código tende a ser mais simples
- A aplicação funciona como se espera naquela plataforma e usa tudo o que está disponível nela

Mas

- Tem que gerar um executável monolítico e não pode compartilhar com outras aplicações
- A maior parte do desenvolvimento, mas não todo, deve ser feito para cada plataforma, o que gera uma certa duplicação
- A manutenção tem que ser feita em cada código de cada plataforma
- A aplicação é o que é, se quer melhorá-la com algo extra, não tem a opção de fazer isto dinamicamente, tem que gerar outra aplicação

É óbvio que se não precisa de mais de uma plataformas facilita a escolha já que não precisa compartilhar nada.

O PCL pode ser mais útil se precisa fazer aplicações para várias plataformas de forma rápida e barata, mesmo que o resultado não seja tão bom. Também é interessante se será comum o usuário ter várias aplicações diferentes com uma mesma base rodando em seu dispositivo.

O Shared é mais interessante quando se deseja o melhor resultado possível em cada plataforma e em geral a aplicação será única com essa base.

Mais pode ser lido em [Xamarin.Forms Portable ou Xamarin.Forms Shared](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127567/101)