# Xamarin.Forms - Projeto Compartilhado x PCL

Tags: .net, xamarin

Quando eu um projeto no Xamarin.Forms, ele permite escolher entre:

Projeto Compartilhado e PCL.

Qual a diferença entre os dois?
Quais vantagens e desvantagens?

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127567/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186582/101

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Xamarin.Forms Portable ou Xamarin.Forms Shared](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127567/xamarin-forms-portable-ou-xamarin-forms-shared)

Answer (score 0):

Projetos compartilhados tem um conceito muito similar a arquivos e pastas compartilhadas. Ambos os projetos, Android, IOS e Winphone, terão acesso as mesmas pastas e arquivos, e qualquer alteração feita de um dos projetos irá refletir diretamente nos outros.

Neste tipo de projeto é muito comum encontrar muitas diretivas de compilação, para execução de recursos específicos de cada plataforma:

```
#if Android
    // Escreva um código utilizando um recurso do android
#endif
```

Já projetos PCL (Portable Class Library), como o próprio nome já diz, são projetos que permitem a criação de códigos compatíveis entre as plataformas alvo.
Uma vez que você inicia a criação deste tipo de projeto a própria IDE irá lhe perguntar quais as plataformas você irá atender com sua PCL, e então irá carregar os assemblies necessários, e compatíveis entre elas.

Por se tratar de Sistemas Operacionais (SO) diferentes, então nem todos os recursos estão disponíveis em cada um deles, e é isto que torna a PCL interessante, já que podemos escrever um código reutilizável principalmente a nível de negócio, sem precisamos nos preocupar com a plataforma alvo necessariamente, pois vamos ter acesso apenas aos recursos comuns entre elas.

Neste ponto geralmente surge uma pergunta: E se eu quiser utilizar um recurso específico da plataforma alvo (android por exemplo), mas este recurso não está disponível na PCL, como fazer?

Este tipo de situação é muito recorrente, uma vez que cada SO tem suas APIs, e uma situação bem comum é o uso de recursos de armazenamento local (Storages) dos dispositivos, onde cada um trata a sua maneira.

Para resolver este tipo de problema, geralmente fugimos um pouco da tecnologia em si e utilizamos recursos de designe de código como [IOC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invers%C3%A3o_de_controle), onde passamos as plataformas específicas a responsabilidade de nos devolver um recurso capaz de resolver problemas específicos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Se eu utilizar SQLIte, que tipo seria mais indicado?

Comment: @Roberta, não entendi o que você quis dizer com tipo mais indicado, poderia exemplificar onde/como você quer utiliza-lo?

Comment: Quero criar um APP para IOS e Android, no Xamarin.Forms. Um App de Noticias por exemplo, onde irei armazenar elas dentro do SQLite (depois de buscar via JSON). Neste cenário, qual é mais indicado, PCL ou ou compartilhado?

Comment: @Roberta, neste cenário eu utilizaria PCL, mas seria uma escolha particular minha devido ao que citei acima, não posso dizer para você, use este ou aquele, pois inclusive vai contra as boas práticas de respostas do fórum.