# Como criar um aplicativo multi plataforma?

Tags: .net, cross-platform

Vamos lá e criamos um aplicativo legal, um sistema baseado em *Console Application*, escrito em Visual Basic.NET, em .NET Framework, ai você quer **portar esse aplicativo para outras plataformas**, mas sem criar uma dependência de cada plataforma, você quer criar a sua própria plataforma, como por exemplo o Java, uma linguagem de programação *cross-platform* que é independente, criaram seu próprio *framework*.

Agora, como posso transformar meu aplicativo em um aplicativo independente de outras plataformas? Como eu posso escrever meu *framework* sem depender do .NET Framework para rodar em outras plataformas também? A pergunta pode gerar muitas respostas, mas o onde quero chegar é como posso fazer o meu sistema ser perfeitamente *Cross-Platform* para rodar em um Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, Android (e/ou outros) sem alterar meu código?

Comment: Mesmo o Java (e o .NET) têm de escrever implementações diferentes de sua *runtime* para cada plataforma que pretendam dar suporte. No máximo, a maioria do código é igual e só muda a parte que faz interface com o sistema operacional. E se um SO oferece um recurso que os outros não oferecem, você tem que escolher entre não usar/oferecer esse recurso ou então abrir mão do "perfeitamente" *cross-platform*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa do [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) *atualmente só .NET mesmo, mas não é o Framework) que é a nova implementação do .NET. Ele funciona nos três principais sistemas operacionais desktop.

Para os sistemas operacionais de dispositivos móveis pode usar o [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) *que agora é o .NET). Funciona nas 3 principais plataformas. Veja mais em [O Xamarin é uma opção viável para desenvolvimento mobile?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90871/101) e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38752/101.

Tanto o .NET Core quanto o Xamarin são completamente suportados pela Microsoft. E compatíveis na sua essência. Se fizer o básico, o que fizer com um rodará no outro.

Também tem o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) que funciona no desktop mas hoje tem pouco motivo para usá-lo, você precisa ter uma necessidade específica para compensar sua adoção. Em dispositivos móveis ele até funciona mas de forma tão limitada e com esforço adicional que duvido que exista um caso que compense seu uso. Ele tende a ficar em segundo plano com a adoção do .NET Core.

Não há como criar aplicações 100% *cross platform*. Sempre terá que usar bibliotecas específicas, terá que escrever códigos pensando nas diferenças dos sistemas operacionais.

Java vende essa ideia de que você faz um código e roda em qualquer lugar, mas não te conta que é preciso esforço seu e que em alguns casos fica ruim em todos os sistemas operacionais.

Os detalhes específicos do que precisa fazer para garantir que roda bem em todas plataformas é melhor perguntar de forma específica quando for tendo problemas.

Seria interessante conhecer o [.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) que é a forma portável de desenvolver aplicações. [Com o .NET 5 isso passa ser menos relevante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Answer (score 5):

A versão do .NET que permite esse recurso multiplataforma é a Mono. O Mono possui uma ferramenta que [verifica se seu projeto está apto para ser migrado](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/).

Feito isso, pode ser necessário alterar alguma coisa, graficamente falando. [Os Toolkits do Mono estão aqui](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/).