# Disponibilizar PDF na versão mobile é prejudicar a experiência do usuário?

Tags: aplicação-web, mobile, ux

Em um projeto em que participo desenvolvendo as camadas Front-End, me deparei com um possível problema prestes a finalizar a versão mobile do mesmo.

A tal proposta a ser questionada, está em um certo trecho do site, em que há uma disponibilidade do Cardápio em PDF ao visitante, proporcionando a impressão ou o possibilidade de efetuar o download do Documento.

Este PDF não é criado via script(PHP ou alguma LIB), é um documento estático  "*uppado*" pelo usuário/cliente.

Na versão desktop, a proposta talvez não prejudique tanto a experiencia, mesmo levando em consideração que o arquivo possa ter alguns Mega Bytes excessivos (foi feito por um Designer que exagerou um pouco na caneta digital).

Na versão mobile/tablets, é obvio que esses Mega Bytes comedores de DADOS além de possivelmente acabar com os "créditos, animo, paciência, (entre outras situações frustrantes) do usuário, uma versão mais "leve" deste Documento torna-se obrigação "socioeconômico"(e por que não?) dos detentores do projeto.

**Mas ai vem a pergunta:**

Será que mesmo que uma versão mais leve seja a solução coerente para o usuário Mobile?

Acredito que grande parte do público alvo que o Site/Projeto tenta atender já teve alguma experiência com o uso de documentos PDF alguma vez na vida, logo, em questão de *uso*, o *usuário* não se "perderia". Mas a pessoa que entra pelo Smartphone/Cel/Tablet deseja esse tipo de situação?

Particularmente eu não gosto muito de me deparar com PDF no Celular, mas e o "Povão", aceita isso? É convencionalmente uma boa ideia praticar isso?

Comment: Imagina um pdf de 3mb e um usuário que tem 10mb de pacote de dados para gastar, na minha opinião(que vale aqui nos comentarios :P) o ideal seria fazer um html especial/leve para mobile.

Comment: Recentemente o Whats up liberou o envio de arquivos PDF no aplicativo. Muita gente pode usar a versão com WiFi. Acho válido você dar uma amostra pro usuário com os dados simplificados e perguntar antes se ele quer gerar o PDF completo com diversos megas, estimando mais ou menos o tamanho do arquivo. Assim ele decide o que é melhor pra ele.

Comment: Apresentar cardápio em PDF pra consulta no navegador é ruim em qualquer dispositivo. Até em imagem fica menos desagradável. Se é um site, basta fazer em HTML, não? O PDF pode ser um mero link pra download, caso a pessoa queira ver offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, vamos entender bem o objetivo do usuário nesse contexto de tarefa. Pelo que eu entendi (você não descreveu detalhes da aplicação), o usuário está acessando o site do restaurante e deseja simplesmente acessar o cardápio. Mas você não ofereceu informações essenciais, tais como: o cardápio é do dia? ou seria um cardápio fixo?

Essas informações podem mudar completamente a nossa percepção (como projetistas) de que algo é mais fácil ou difícil de prejudicar a experiência do usuário. Quer ver?

### Cenário 1: Baixando PDF

Suponha que o cardápio é fixo. Isto é, ele é completo (tem todas as opções oferecidas pelo restaurante) e não muda com muita frequência (e, por isso, provavelmente não inclui os valores das opções oferecidas). Nesse caso, não há tanto mal em permitir que o usuário baixe o cardápio mesmo sendo um PDF grande. *Se o tamanho do arquivo for informado claramente antes do download* (um critério importante de usabilidade é a clareza das informações), o usuário pode decidir por baixar o PDF em casa em seu Wifi. *Se ele também souber previamente que o cardápio é completo*, ele pode mesmo assim decidir por baixar o PDF usando seu acesso móvel (e pagando o custo relacionado), pois deseja o cardápio e sabe que uma vez baixado não precisará fazê-lo novamente (pois o PDF já estará no dispositivo, facilmente acessível).

Nesse caso, a usabilidade da leitura do cardápio fica em parte por conta do designer (e, convenhamos, um cardápio bem feito é atraente e produz inúmeras outras vantagens hedônicas para o negócio) e em parte pelo leitor de PDF usado pelo cliente, que você simplesmente não tem controle.

Se, por outro lado, o cardápio não é fixo ou não tem tudo o que é oferecido (por exemplo, ele muda todos os dias, todas as semanas), é terrivelmente ruim para o usuário ter que baixar vários PDFs diferentes. Não somente pelo custo de transmissão, mas pelo gerenciamento que isso requer. Nesse caso, esse cenário não é mesmo interessante (e eu diria que também não é interessante para um acesso via Desktop!).

### Cenário 2: Acesso Dinâmico

Suponha então que o cardápio não é fixo. Nesse cenário, o cliente abre o site do restaurante e o sistema apresenta imediatamente os dados do cardápio do dia (ou do momento desejado pelo cliente). Talvez seja mais difícil permitir que o dono do restaurante mude facilmente as informações ali contidas (afinal, usando PDF o cara pode simplesmente ir no Word, fazer um cardápio qualquer e gerar em PDF para colocar no site), mas por outro lado o acesso é centralizado e retira do usuário (o cliente do restaurante) qualquer necessidade de precisar ele mesmo gerenciar os possíveis cardápios que vão ser gerados ao longo do tempo.

Um design bonito e agradável continua igualmente importante para o engajamento do cliente do restaurante. E se você parar pra pensar, os custos de transmissão/download envolvidos não vão mudar tanto assim, pois as imagens, layout e textos coloridos que seriam baixados em um PDF são agora diretamente transmitidos no HTML. Mas o conteúdo é essencialmente o mesmo! Isto é, o seu designer pode ter também uma mão pesada na caneta tinteiro digital fazendo os CSS's! rs

Assim, esse cenário tende a ser melhor para a experiência porque o usuário tem a sensação de que o acesso é centralizado e facilitado, e de que a informação é garantidamente atualizada. Além de que ele não precisa ter o esforço cognitivo de saber onde raios ele baixou o último PDF do cardápio da segunda-feira.

### Cenário 3: O Melhor dos Dois Mundos

Talvez o restaurante não tenha um cardápio realmente muito variável. Mas isso não quer dizer que ele não mude, que promoções eventuais não ocorram. E ainda assim você deseja (acredite em mim, vc deseja! rs) que o cliente do restaurante não tenha trabalho algum em lembrar onde acessar a informação que ele precisa. Então, uma abordagem em que você pode ter o melhor dos dois cenários anteriores é construindo tanto um site como um aplicativo para ser instalado no dispositivo móvel do cliente.

É verdade que a percepção do cliente a respeito da "necessidade" de instalar mais um aplicativo é complexa. Mas ela decorre exatamente da importância do conteúdo pra ele. Se o usuário acessa o cardápio uma vez, talvez seja porque esteja interessado em conhecer o restaurante. Mas se acessa frequentemente, é porque já gosta de comer lá e quer só saber o que tem pra janta hoje. Idealmente a sua solução deveria contar com o site para facilitar o acesso casual do primeiro tipo de usuário, e um aplicativo para facilitar o acesso do segundo.

O site simplesmente exibiria o cardápio tal como o faz na Web. Poderia até ser em um PDF, se ele pudesse ser exibido diretamente no navegador sem precisar ser baixado para uma pasta qualquer (isto é, o usuário só enxerga o conteúdo - o sistema operacional faz o download em uma pasta temporária). Afinal, lembre-se: estou considerando esse acesso móvel como de interesse inicial, casual.

O aplicativo, instalado pelo usuário menos casual e já frequentador assíduo do restaurante, também requer uma conexão com a Internet para baixar os dados. Mas o fato de ser um aplicativo local te permite construir um sistema de cache, em que você armazena o cardápio mais recente no dispositivo e apenas atualiza-o quando necessário (por um esquema de push, talvez, já que você pode até mesmo exibir promoções pontuais dessa forma).

A [decisão por construir ou não um aplicativo é polêmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73289/73), principalmente do ponto de vista do dono do restaurante (que vai ter que pagar o dobro). Mas a minha experiência me diz que faz todo o sentido construir algo assim quando há realmente algum ganho para o usuário, como me parece ser o caso do seu cenário. Nele há ganho no cache do cardápio e no fato de que o usuário não precisa saber onde tal informação fica armazenada para ter a parcepção de que ela é atual.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado,muito obrigado mesmo!
Ok, sobre os Cenários, desculpe o pobre detalhamento a respeito da minha situação.
Acredito que o Cenário 1 é o mais próximo da realidade(investimento) do cliente, já que o projeto do cenário 3 não seria possível[que ao meu ver é o melhor]. Como a escolha dos cenários não são baseadas apenas em poder aquisitivo, mas sim no melhor encadeamento nas decisões do projeto, tenho expor melhor os dados essenciais como, tamanho do arquivo, frequência de mudança e se possível uma versão prévia em HTML, como havia recomendado para adequar melhor o projeto.

Comment: Por nada. Talvez você possa fazer os dois no cenário 1. Isto é, ofereça uma página HTML para acesso online das informações, e *também* um link para o PDF (claro, indicando informações como o tamanho do arquivo e preferencialmente tendo dentro dele a data da atualização). Um usuário que *preferir* baixar o PDF, vai ficar feliz em ter acesso offiline às informações.

Comment: O projeto trata-se de uma lanchonete escolar que além da prestação convencional atendendo os alunos da instituição(tá ai o uso do cardápio), atende a Buffets e encomendas, delivery de almoço, além das certificações de padrão de qualidade da cozinha e nutrição. Dentre os objetivos e público-alvo, foi projetado este espaço para pais e alunos acessarem diariamente. Está mais do que na hora de começar a participar nas projeções do layout. rsrs

Comment: Bom, talvez essa seja a única lanchonete disponível na escola e por pior que seja a experiência os usuários vão usar assim mesmo (por falta de alternativa). Mas, mesmo assim, eu diria pra vc analisar bem quem são os usuários. São só os pais, ou os pais *e também* os alunos? Todos esses potenciais usuários lidam bem com o download de PDFs no celular? Isto é, eles sabem fazer o download e depois acessar novamente o PDF já gravado no disco? Porque se não souberem, vão acessar tal como fariam com uma página HTML (baixando-toda-santa-vez). E ai, o propósito de usar PDF se perde. Enfim, cuidado.